# Idea of improvement

Tags: feature-request, comments, comment-voting

Wouldn't it be great if I asked a question, someone comments, below the question, then if any other comments answer the question, I could click a button and mark it as an answer and the whole comment could be the actual answer :) Which a tick or something like that just would save some time :)

Comment: Most folks simply [ask the commenter to repost](http://www.google.com/search?q=site:stackoverflow.com+%22so+I+can+accept+it%22) the comment as an answer. Would we really need another button for that?

Comment: I think many people have low answering % because sometimes they can't mark the right answer :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd have to see numbers on how often this happens before I'd get behind it.  Sure, I've seen it before, but it's a tiny fraction of questions that get answered in the comments.  I don't know if we need a new feature to deal with a small fraction of cases, particularly when most of those can be rectified by asking the commenter to post an answer.  (I've done this before.  If you leave them a comment telling them you want to upvote their answer, people usually jump right on it.)